# For a desired action in the end of the current period of time, should I use "would be" or "would have been"?

Tags: subjunctives

When talking about some desired action that did not transpire toward the end of the period of time, which is coming to a close during the moment of speaking, should I use "would be" or "would have been"?

> "Well, besides the fact that he likes cherry pies (something that I
>   became aware of on my very first day of acquaintance with him) there
>   wasn't any more information of interest this year that I **would** be able
>   to have gotten out of Peter about him."

The period of time in the example above is "this year". It's not over yet, but it's ending soon. And it looks like getting any further interesting personal info from Peter is very unlikely now, though not totally impossible.

Comment: Minor note: *something that I became aware on* doesn't work. It should be *something that I became aware **of** on*. (Or, theoretically, *something **of which** I became aware on*. But that's awkward.)

Answer (score 1):

"There wasn't any more information of interest that I would have been able to get out of Peter this year."  (We don't need "about him" because that is clear from the context.)

"Would have (past participle)" is a good pattern to use.  Here are a couple more examples:

- I would have been happy to take you with me if I had known you wanted to go along.
- I would have had a nap if I had known we would be up so late.